# Google Analytics custom report of events

Tags: seo, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, tag-manager

I want to create a custom report of some of the event tracking that I am doing on my site. After creating my report, the report does not show any events listed with the event category name that I am interested in. I know that there are events, because when I view the 'Top Events' section under the 'Behavior' tab, I see the event category that I'm interested in.

To simplify that:

1. I have verified that my event (created through google tag manager) is working and is showing up in analytics under the correct category name that I created.
2. Without changing the timeframe, I created a custom report as a `Flat Table` using `Event Action`, `Event Label`, and `Event Category` as the `dimensions`, and `Event Value` as the `metric`.
3. Viewing this report shows me no events with my event category that I'm searching for. (Obviously, adding a filter to this report for the event category that I want produces 0 results).

The report that I made should show me all events, should it not? Why doesn't my event category show up in custom reports when it shows up in provided reports under the `behavior` tab?

Comment: You might be including an incompatible dimension, or maybe you're date range it out. Adjust your date range to something where you know you had events, and then create a simple report first, with "Event Category", "Event Action", and "Event Label" as the dimensions, and "Unique Events" as a metric. Also, make sure you have "Event Value" associated with those events, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Reports will only display dimensions which have values. The reason why the event is not showing is that is has nothing to 'show'.

My assumption is that the event of interest has no event value, and consequently does not show in the report. The reason why it shows in the report under the Behavior tab is that there are other fields where the event has values (e.g. total events, unique events).

The easiest fix is to include "Total Event" or "Unique Events" in your custom report.

Comment: Adding the `total event` metric did indeed populate my report with results of my event category. What is interesting is that `event value` is '0', which speaks to your point about having nothing to show. However, in tag manager, the `event label` field is populated with the exact same thing as the `event value` field, so why would `event value` be '0' when `event label` is showing data? Can `event value` only be numeric perhaps?

Comment: Yea, it must be a numeric value as it will be aggregated. Event values are intended for passing a dynamic 'value' of an interaction into Google Analytics.

Comment: Ok, great. So really that was my only issue then. Thanks!